# Unable to compile android project after upgrading android version to 8.0.0

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I was implementing an **android app** in  **java** that was running without any problem but after upgrading my **gradle** , my code can't compile anymore and I got the error:

```
Configuration cache state could not be cached: field `compileTimeDependencies` of task `:app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug` of type `com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.databinding.DataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsTask`: error writing value of type 'org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection'
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.budiyev.android:code-scanner:2.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.whiteelephant:monthandyearpicker:1.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
```